# How do I store items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason, when pressing 'R' attempting to store an item on a corpse (haven't tried other containers) in TES: Skyrim,  the game doesn't respond. This prevents me from completing the quest 'Breaching Security'. The R key otherwise works. The console command 'setstage' seems to bug up with Breaching Security, not letting me advance the DB storyline (though the quest registers as completed).

Notes:

- My keybindings are normal. I tried remapping the R key, it didn't affect anything. (Also, it still tells me to press 'R' to store items no matter what the weapon sheath/unsheath is mapped to).
- I don't have a message displayed when I try to store something.
- Addendum: I can drop items normally by pressing R, so it's not even an error to do with the inventory screen, just with the storing function.
- Addendum 2: I tried updating to the latest patch, it didn't resolve this problem.
- Addendum 3: Storing items works on other people's computers with a Skyrim installation, on the same savefile.

Can anyone offer a fix for the storage issue or a way to advance the Breaching Security quest otherwise?

Comment: Have you remapped the R key (weapon sheath/unsheath)?

Comment: Do you have a message displayed when you try to store something?

Comment: When you're not storing anything, can you sheathe and unsheathe your weapon with the key?

Answer (score 1):

Check your key-bindings.  Also be careful about where you store items.  I believe that items can disappear if you store them in random barrels, and sacks.  The safest way to store items are in containers in your own home.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps don't enter the inventory mode with him and instead stand over him so that you get an activate prompt.

Comment: The problem is not with this quest in particular, I can't store items in general (Today I resolved the quest problem by doing the 'storing' part on a friend's computer)